# Call Shortcode on wp_footer

Tags: shortcode, footer

Is it possible to call shortcode outside of post/ page content area? I am trying to add it to wp_footer with the following codes but it's returning string:

```
add_shortcode('eps_pop', 'init');
function indtable_display_front_end($atts ) {
global $post;

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => ''  
    ),  $atts ) );

echo get_post_meta($id, '_my_meta_value_key', true);
}
echo do_shortcode('[eps_pop id="234"]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_shortcode('eps_pop', 'indtable_display_front_end');
function indtable_display_front_end($atts ) {
global $post;

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => ''  
    ),  $atts ) );

echo get_post_meta($id, '_my_meta_value_key', true);
}
echo do_shortcode('[eps_pop id="234"]');
```

Comment: Ohhh... my God.. I forgot to change that function name.. Thanks Dude..!